# How to declare native cpp method for which declared in kotlin companion object?

Tags: android, android-ndk, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have a Kotlin class which just declare some methods for interaction of Kotlin and C/C++ :

```
class JNILib {

    companion object {

        external fun getAppId(): String

        init {
            System.loadLibrary("native-code")
        }
    }
}
```

But I have a problem when declaring the native method. I tried

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_package_JNILib_getAppId(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject /* this */){
    // wrong
}

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_package_JNILib_Companion_getAppId(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject /* this */){
    // wrong
}
```

Comment: How about `Java_com_package_JNILib_00024Companion_getAppId`? Another way would be to annotate the method with `@JvmStatic` in kotlin. Then the C++ declaration ought to be `Java_com_package_JNILib_getAppId(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz)`.

Comment: @Michael using `00024Companion` is a little werid, but I think `@JvmStatic` is the right answer. could you please post an answer?

Comment: https://medium.com/yalantis-android/android-ndk-calling-kotlin-from-native-code-40a1cb0f6164

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The companion object is realized as an instance of an inner class `JNILib$Companion`. That `$` must be present in the C++ function's signature, and [the way you accomplish that](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html) is by using the escape sequence `_0XXXX`, where XXXX is the unicode character code. The character code for `$` is hex 24, i.e. the escape sequence is `_00024`, which means that your C++ function name becomes `Java_com_package_JNILib_00024Companion_getAppId`.

Alternatively, you could make `getAppId` a static method of `JNILib` by annotating it with [`@JvmStatic`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-static/index.html). Your C++ function name should then be `Java_com_package_JNILib_getAppId`, with the arguments `JNIEnv *, jclass` (note the `jclass` instead of `jobject` since `getAppId` now is a class method rather than an instance method).